# Why isnt WPF displaying an accented character correctly?

Tags: wpf, text, character-encoding, webclient, downloadstring

I'm downloading a webpage, and then loading strings from the page into a WPF UI.
One string has an accented character: "Ãine".
In the debugger, the string looks fine, but when added to a WPF ListBox, it appears like this: Ã[]ine, where [] is a single rectangular symbol.
When I copy the text from the debugger UI and paste it, a space appears after the Ã. This 'space' shows up as the rectangular symbol when displayed by WPF.

Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: I imagine that in WPF you're dealing with UTF-8, and the listbox is expecting Latin-1 (or similar).

Comment: ListBox surely accepts the format that a System.String is in (Unicode?). The weird thing is that the VS debugger UI is fine with the string. It is maybe a problem with the download from the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was to download the webpage like this:

```
WebClient c = new WebClient();
var bytes = c.DownloadData(url);
UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();
var s = utf8.GetString(bytes);
```

instead of like this:

```
WebClient c = new WebClient();
var s = c.DownloadString(url);
```

`WebClient.DownloadString` was unable to properly download the page and convert it to a string.

Answer (score 0):

Your string might contain an "invisible" char that got there from a copy/paste or something. Try rewriting "Ãine" character by character.

Comment: The string is extracted from a webpage, so manually editing it isn't a solution.